# Using Database first approach in Entity framework, how to fetch the data from a single table only which has multiple foreign key relationship?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I am using Database first approach in Entity framework. I have two tables i.e. Person and Role table.
Person table has 3 columns

- PersonId
- Name
- RoleId

Role table has 2 columns

- RoleId
- RoleName

The automated generated classes for these two tables are below along with the foreign key relationship.

```
public partial class Role
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Role()
    {
        this.People = new HashSet<Person>();
    }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}

public partial class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

I used following code to retrieve the data from Role table

```
    public List<Role> GetRole()
    {
        var _context= new TestDBEntities();
        List<Role> data = new List<Role>();
        data  = _context.Roles.ToList();
        return data;
    }
```

While retrieving the data from the Role table, all the data from the Role table was retrieved but the Person table data was also retrieved along with it. The reason behind it must be the relationship between these two tables. So, I want to fetch the data only from the Role table. Can anyone assist me on how to fetch the data from the Role table only without the data from Person?

Comment: How do you know that Person list is also loaded?

Comment: I am using break point for debugging, so I could see the person list within the row of the Role data

Comment: Ivan below answers why this i happening. If you remove 'virtual' keyword from ICollection<Person>, this will not appear until you load related objects manually.

Comment: I solved it but I do not have to remove 'virtual' keyword from ICollection<Person>. Rather, I disabled the lazyloading in the constructor of the EntitiesClass that inherits the DbContext.     `public TestDBEntities() : base("name=TestDBEntities") { this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The related data is **not** retrieved by the shown code, but when some other code does access `People` property for the first time. It could be the debugger variables window or some serialization code.

This behavior is called [Lazy Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#lazy). It can be disabled in a several ways, the easiest is to remove the `virtual` keyword from the navigation properties. In Code First you would do that directly in the code, in the EDMX designer I guess there must be some property controlling the generated property accessor. Or using the techniques described in the [Selective disabling of lazy loading with Database First method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001275/selective-disabling-of-lazy-loading-with-database-first-method) thread.

Comment: While looking at the break point, I can see the row of the Role data has the Person property (because of relationship between Person and Role table) and it contains the Person data. So the above mentioned code is fetching the Role data as well as the Person data within the row of the Role data. I'll try the technique that you have mentioned above and let u know about it.

Comment: How do you see it? In a debugger, right? See the first paragraph of the answer. Actually there is no way to see if it's loaded or not because once you "look" at the property, it gets loaded - that's the side effect of the lazy loading.

Comment: Thank you @Ivan for your answer. I solved the issue by including `public TestDBEntities()
            : base("name=TestDBEntities")
        {
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }`   in the constructor of the TestDBEntities class which inherits the DbContext.  It worked for me. Now the Person table data can be fetched without retrieving the data from the foreign key table.

Comment: You are welcome, glad that helped solving the issue. The solution you choose is one of the "several ways" I mentioned and is explained in the "Turn off lazy loading for all entities" section of the "Lazy Loading" link. So you pick the one that is most appropriate for your case.